# merging multiple oData calls into a single call

Tags: httprequest, odata

I have a WCF service (C#) which uses oData to provide 3 different recommendations for 3 different modules on the website.

Currently the client makes 3 seperate calls to get recommendations (JSON) for each module.

We are looking to merge the 3 http calls into a single call, I am not sure how this can be achieved with our existing oData setup, can someone please guide me int he right direction?

Example :

Recommendation Module 1 request :

```
http://localhost:13126/DataService.svc/Recommendations(10013)
```

Recommendation Module 2 request:

```
http://localhost:13126/DataService.svc/Recommendations?$filter=ZoneName eq 'somename'
```

Recommendation Module 1 request:

```
http://localhost:13126/DataService.svc/Recommendations$filter=zoneid=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OData Batch Processing](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/batch-processing/).

WCF-related documentation is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744839%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (client) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2008/04/06/batching-data-service-requests.aspx) (team article).

**Edit:** Or not, you probably want to read [this thread](http://www.imc.org/atom-protocol/mail-archive/msg10751.html) about leveraging HTTP pipelining instead.